# Bind mount ONLY if Samba mount is present? (Ex: BIND MOUNT Requires NFS Mount \\172.16.x.x\files... )

Tags: linux, bind, nfs, samba, mount

I have a mount with SAMBA using the following in fstab:

```
//source/files /mnt/files cifs user,_netdev,cache=none,credentials=/usr/src/access.smb 0 0
```

And then i have the following mount --bind line:

```
/mnt/files /var/www/html/data none defaults,bind 0 0
```

But the second mount is not working. If i reboot the computer only the first mount works.
I need to manually mount the second one (Using bind)

Please, can someone help me?
I saw this post on Unix Stack Exchange but i did'nt understand: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216287/how-do-i-set-up-bind-mounts-on-startup-correctly-in-the-systemd-world

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
/mnt/files /var/www/html/data none x-systemd.requires=/mnt/files,x-systemd.automount,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Hello! Sorry - Something like this or is your comment actually the solution?

Comment: Just try it. Possibly, some some corrections might be needed

Comment: Also, please: What does x-systemd.automount do ? I read this documentation, here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html# but i didnt really understanding... Do you know what is it for or did you find this elsewhere ? Thank you.

Comment: I think this worked but i did'nt use this systemd.automount option since i didnt understand what it does .. Thank, if you could just complement specifiying what systemd.automount i would be glad. Have a superb day :)

Comment: It dynamically creates systemd  mount units from fstab entries

Comment: For some reason when i test it with this x-systemd.automount option it doesnt mount.